# Laravel 6: Auth login gives blank screen after composer update. No solution helps, even with reverted production copy or fresh project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Ok I'm really at the end of my rope here. After a composer update and a few more commits on rather unrelated stuff I noticed that logging in sent me to a blank screen instead to home as it should. I'm using the debugbar but this doesn't get loaded either.

I revert the changes, no effect. I reverted the composer update, no effect. I reinstalled XAMPP going over all the settings, no effect. I copied back the code of the production server, which is only a few more commits lagging behind, still no effect. I took the composer.json from a fresh Laravel app, still no effect. I install a completely new project, add the auth scaffold with these commands, run NPM, adjust the .env to work with the old DB (still using the correct field names) and now it gives me a 419 - page expired?.

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

SO I'm using the Laravel Auth scaffolding and I'll admit I'm not in depth familiar with how it works exactly.

I pass the construct of the LoginController here using the route('login')

```
/**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
```

Then Kernel sends me with this middleware to App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'permission' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPermission::class,
        'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

(oh and I tried to uncomment AuthenticateSession, no effect).

And this is where it goes wrong. The function handle() never gets fired. If I put a dd() in front of the if statement it doesn't get triggered. And I really don't know where to look in between the LoginController's construct and the middleware for a problem (nor would I likely even recognize it, I'm not that advanced of a Laravel programmer yet).

Problem however is that I never touched this code. And even If I did, the revert should have wiped it. And if that didn't, copying back the code from the production server shouldn't have failed either. And why the hell is the new install not working for a problem that was seemingly caused by some commits.

The next step was looking the XXAMP setting I guess, but I completely reinstalled all that just to make sure and it's working. And this shouldn't be it because I can browse the pages of the site just fine as long as I don't try to login. Using Laravel 6.x and PHP 7.3.12 (came with the fresh XAMPP).

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.2",
        "ajthinking/tinx": "^2.1",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^5.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "6.x",
        "laravel/helpers": "^1.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0",
        "nunomaduro/phpinsights": "^1.11",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "~2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/Http/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Also I can't find very useful precedent as they seem to be mostly years old beginner's questions or have similar problems but aren't answered.. I could really use a experienced Laravel programmer's look at this, as I really have NO idea at this point what the hell is going wrong.

Comment: did you compile you js files? you need to compile you js files

Answer (score 0):

As per Andy Song's suggestion: I had to run NPM as well, after `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

Run this commands step by step:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do check whether you have npm installed or not?

if not use this commands to update or install npm

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

**Commands are:**

composer require laravel/ui

**For viewjs:** php artisan ui vue --auth

**For Reactjs:** php artisan ui react --auth

**For Bootstrap:** php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

npm install

npm run dev